# See all changed and staged files in Xcode 9

Tags: git, xcode9

## How to see a list of all changed files (pending stage & commit) with Xcode 9?

I don't see an option in Source Control Navigator (keyboard shortcut: command-2) or Source Control menu option.

List of files corresponding to `git status` command on terminal. Also, if possible `git diff --staged`.

Please add **a keyboard shortcut** if any.

Answer (score 19):

The closest thing Xcode has is a button at the bottom of the project navigator to show only files with source-control status. Clicking the button shows files that have uncommitted changes.

[image]

Comment: I would love to have a keyboard shortcut for this one. Any ?

Comment: If there's a keyboard shortcut, it would be in Xcode's Key Bindings preferences.

Comment: unfortunately as of Xcode 12, there still isn't one for this highly used feature

Answer (score 7):

As Mark answered you can filter all the modified files, after that don't forget to turn on **Comparison**, so you can see where the code got changed.

[image]